# How to check if message was sent by certain user discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I am using discord.py to make my discord bot and when somebody types a message I want to check if the user is lets say foo#3645 and then do something if it is not then do something else

```
if(messageAuthor == "foo#3645):
    # do something
else:
    # do something else
```

I tried this:

```
if(ctx.message.author == "foo#3465"):
    # do something
```

but that is not working for some reason...

If you need more info please comment.

Comment: `ctx.message.author` doesn't contain the name, I believe you're looking for `ctx.message.author.name` (see https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html?highlight=author#discord.Member). Though you're better off using the ID as MCO answered.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if you want a reliable check, check for user ids:

```
if author.id == 170733454822341405:
   #do something
```

Answer (score 5):

The `str` representation of a `User` (including `Member`s) will be their username (not their server-specific nickname), and the discriminator (used to tell people with the same username apart).

```
if str(ctx.message.author) == "foo#3465":
    ...
```

That said, you should be checking against `id`s, as it is possible for a person to change their Discord username.  `id`s are strings in the async branch of [discord.py](/questions/tagged/discord.py) and integers in [discord.py-rewrite](/questions/tagged/discord.py-rewrite)

Answer (score 1):

Checking for a user ID is your best bet. According to the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#user), `User.id` is an integer, not a string, so the accepted answer may not work. `message.author` is of type `User`.

This is what worked for me:

```
if message.author.id = 170733454822341405:
    #do something
```

To get someone's user ID manually, enable developer mode in discord (user settings -> appearance -> advanced), then just right click on a user anywhere and click copy ID.